# How to set directory in header in php

Tags: javascript, php, css, import, directory

I have a small problem with importing links. Once I started using pretty URL directories stops working. What can I do ?

Screenshots:

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your css and js links dynamic.
For example:

```
<?php define( 'SCRIPT_ROOT',  'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/' );?>
<link href="<?php echo SCRIPT_ROOT ?>site/static/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
```

After this doesnt matter your directory structure.

Comment: Have fun mate! :P